# Validation Metrics Peaking to Extreme Values

Tags: loss-functions, validation

I am training a 3D Unet model with MAE loss to synthesis MRI scans from CT scans. The learning rate is 10e-3, and I am running it with a batch size of 6 through 600 epochs. The validation loss looks like this:
[image]

This was trained on 102 CT/MRI pairs with 6 validation pairs. I then tried with 96 CT/MRI pairs and 12 validation pairs. The validation loss looked like this. However, this is on a different scale:

[image]

Can anyone help with explaining why there are extreme peaks (I do not know how high they peak as I limited the y axis) and what I should do about them?

Thank you very much!